Horror movie in which a teenage girl's family moves into a haunted house
So I watched this horror film a while back so my memory is a bit blurred but I know I really liked it ! 
It's about this family who moves into a house where strange things keep happening and the teenage daughter had like a communication with one of the ghosts I think that tells her things. (Again not sure what) 
Anyway throughout the movie it seems like the time keeps travelling into the ghost girls time and then back to the Alive teenage girls time revealing the things that happened in the house and I think the father is a suspect or kept hurting his family, but anyway... the time keeps switching and the days keep starting over again and again and the teenage girl is the only person who knows it.
Language:English
Country: American
Release year : It could have been at least 3 years old. 

Do you remember more specifically when you watched it?  Any idea on whether it's new or old (guess at a release year?)  Language?  What country are you in / was the movie from?

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

It could have been about 3 years ago minimum, it was American I am Canadian it was English

Could be Haunter ( 2013)


Lisa Johnson, the ghost of a teenage girl who becomes aware that she
  is dead, haunts a house somewhere in northern Ontario. Along with her
  parents and brother, who are unaware that they are dead, she is stuck
  on the same day they were murdered in 1985. As she becomes more aware
  of her circumstances, she realizes that she can make contact with
  people in other timelines. As she explores this ability, a pale man
  appears and warns her to stop. Undeterred, Lisa uses personal items
  from other people killed in the house to make a connection with
  Olivia, part of a family living in the house in the future who will
  become the next set of victims.
With the help of Olivia and the spirits of other murdered girls, Lisa
  is transported into the timelines of other victims and unravels the
  mystery of the house, realizing that the previous resident of the
  house, Edgar Mullins, is possessing the fathers of the families who
  live in the house to continue his serial murders. She causes her
  family to come to terms with the knowledge that they are dead, and
  thus "awakened" they become able to assist her. After her family
  escapes to the afterlife, Lisa stays behind to stop Edgar. She is
  nearly trapped in Olivia's body as Mullin moves on to kill them, but
  Lisa is able to escape him long enough to summon the spirits of
  Mullin's past victims, delaying his next kill long enough for the
  spirits of his other victims to join her. As Mullin is 'incinerated'
  in the furnace where he killed his own victims, Olivia's father
  retakes control of his body, confused about what just happened. After
  assuring him and Olivia that they will be a happy family again, Lisa
  goes to sleep, but awakens with her family on her birthday, out of the
  loop that Mullin trapped them in.


Yes that is it!!
